# Valuation of a sum of elements strengthened

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

In the definition of valuation I have, the axioms are:

$val: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \infty$, $K$ is a field

$val(a) = \infty \Leftrightarrow a = 0$

$val(ab) = val(a) + val(b)$

$val(a+b) \geq min(val(a), val(b))$

In other texts, I have seen a strengthening of the second rule

$val(a) \neq val(b) \Rightarrow val(a+b) = min(val(a), val(b))$

I'm struggling to prove this from my axioms, any hints will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Quadruplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482873/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652869/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712415/ .

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find the right phrase to google! @Schoeneberg